# If Statement Not Working on Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

Can anyone explain why this returns false when I try to equate the two? The two are exactly the same.

I'm basically trying to do a validation here and make sure the numbers match up. I want to check if cell B4 equals cell L2 on a different spreadsheet. The value in B4 is $2642.90 and the value in L2 is $2642.90. I set cells E3 to be equal to B4 and E4 to be equal to L2 (on the other sheet), so it is clearer to see the problem.

Thanks in advance!

The image can be found at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/beEqZ.jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this

= IF (EXACT(E3,E4), THEN Whatever)

Comment: It works! Thanks so much!

Though I am a bit curious why it doesn't work? Does Google Sheets do string literals for all of its variables? I've noticed that I've had to use quotes for some comparisons before.